# VSTS build number for build definition

Tags: azure-devops, git-branch, semantic-versioning

I have a few branches in my git repo e.g. master for production, dev for development, qa for testing, etc.

Each branch has it's own build definition, like app-dev, app-qa, app-prod, etc.

I'd like to include build number as a part of artifact name, e.g.  0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.**53** for development or 0.2.0-RC.**12** for testing.

Obviously each build definition's number should be unique.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$(Rev:.r)` Token documented here: [Build number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#build-number-format).

Comment: But this number is related only to a particular date, isn't it? And I can't find it in environment variables on build slave.

Comment: @КагарлицкийДмитрий This depends on how do you define the build number format. If your build number format include tokens like "Build.$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r), it will start from 0 again in the second day as the value of (Date:yyyyMMdd) changed. But if the other strings in your build number format does not change like "Build$(Rev:.r)", it will just keep increasing. This is a Token, not a variable, you need to define it in your build definition->Option->Build Number Format, and then you can use BuildNumber variable to check the value.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the predefined Build.BuildID variable. In your example, your build number definition would look like the following:

- 0.3.0-SnapShot.${Build.BuildId}
- 0.2.0-RC.${Build.BuildId}

All of the predefined variables are available in the [Build Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch) documentation

More information about Build Number formats can be found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work, Job has been executed only 3 times - http://prntscr.com/hlx8gx , but both BUILD_BUILDID & BUILD_BUILDNUMBER are 188 - http://prntscr.com/hlx96j 188 is total number of all jobs executions in the project and doesn't fit to be used as a part of artifact name in particular job

Comment: Build.BuildID is global so it will only be assigned to a single build. if you want to track 'n' number of ID's and increment them on each branch, you would need to do something much more custom and potentially more error prone. However, because you would be adding the BuildId after the 'Patch Version', it should still technically be considered semantic-versioning, but I understand if it does not work for you. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253306/why-is-build-number-an-abuse-of-semantic-versioning

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work, because for dev env we can have dozens of builds every day and only a few staging builds per week. In Jenkins it's BUILD_NUMBER for each job which does exactly what needed.

Comment: We came from the Jenkins world as well and while it was a bit of an adjustment, everyone now understands that the number doesn't have the exact same meaning, but it still does provide value and we've found it actually has helped us identify some dependency gaps in the past. We are in a similar boat too as our current build.id is actually in the 100k range as we speak.